# merge rows data if many NAs in R

Tags: r, na

I have the following data table:

```
library(data.table)
# Example table
table <- data.table(ID = c("Entity_A","Entity_A","Entity_B","Entity_B"),
                  Level = c("Individual_1","Individual_2","Individual_1","Individual_2"),
                  Amount1 = c("100","100","120","n.a."),
                  Amount2 = c("n.a.","40","30","30"),
                  Amount3 =c("20","n.a.","40","n.a."),
                  Amount4 =c("10","n.a.","n.a.","n.a.")
                  )
# Transform "n.a." in real NA
table <- table %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), ~na_if(., "n.a.")))
# Count which rows have more NAs
table$na_count <- apply(table, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
# Show example table
table
         ID        Level Amount1 Amount2 Amount3 Amount4 na_count
1: Entity_A Individual_1     100    <NA>      20      10        1
2: Entity_A Individual_2     100      40    <NA>    <NA>        2
3: Entity_B Individual_1     120      30      40    <NA>        1
4: Entity_B Individual_2    <NA>      30    <NA>    <NA>        3
```

For each entity (Entity A, Entity B, etc... in column "ID"), I would like to take the value available in the rows with the highest number of NAs (from column "na_count") and merge this information with the corresponding row with the minimum number of NAs (if there is actually information to merge).
The resulting data frame would be:

```
         ID        Level Amount1 Amount2 Amount3 Amount4
1: Entity_A Individual_1     100      40      20      10
2: Entity_B Individual_1     120      30      40    <NA>
```

For example, for **Entity A** the Amount2 (previously NA) was not available in the first row (Individual_1, that has the lowest number of NAs for Entity A), but it was actually available in the second row (Individual_2, that has the highest number of NAs for Entity A). So the code should fill the first row with what's available in the second one. While for **Entity B** since in row 4 there was no additional information that could be merged, the final row will continue to be like row 3.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrange` the data by `na_count` and `fill` the `NA` values for each `ID` and select the 1st row in each group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

table %>%
  arrange(ID, na_count) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  fill(starts_with('Amount'), .direction = 'updown') %>%
  slice(1L) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  dplyr::select(-na_count)

#  ID       Level        Amount1 Amount2 Amount3 Amount4
#  <chr>    <chr>        <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#1 Entity_A Individual_1 100     40      20      10     
#2 Entity_B Individual_1 120     30      40      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

As the input is a data.table, we can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
table[order(na_count),lapply(.SD, function(x) 
   nafill(nafill(as.numeric(x), type = 'locf'), type = 'nocb')[1]),
      ID, .SDcols = startsWith(names(table), 'Amount')]
         ID Amount1 Amount2 Amount3 Amount4
1: Entity_A     100      40      20      10
2: Entity_B     120      30      40      NA
```